# error when returning a value of type Double?

Tags: java, android

In this method I return a value of the type Double, but there is an error saying "Method

Must return value of type Double"???

**Code**:

```
public class Gyro extends Activity {

Double gyro_X;
Double gyro_Y;
Double gyro_Z;

public Double getGyro_X() {
    if (this.gyro_X == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+gyro_XIsNullText, ToastdurationShort).show();
    } else { 
    return this.gyro_X;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `this.gyro_x` is `null` you don't return anything...
Your code should be something like

```
public Double getGyro_X() {
    if (this.gyro_X == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+gyro_XIsNullText, ToastdurationShort).show();
        return null;
        //Or maybe: throw new NullPointerException();
    } else { 
    return this.gyro_X;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this.gyro_x is null then the else branch is never entered. You only have a return statement in the else branch. Add one in the if branch or at the end of the method then it should work if this.gyro_x is of type Double.